# Read unsigned chars into string

Tags: c++, strcmp, unsigned-char, memcmp

I have an array of unsigned chars:

```
unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

I want to read in the first N unsigned chars from that array into a string however after looking at `strncpy()`, that seems to only take pointers to signed chars.

Should I be looking at `memcpy()`?

Comment: What is the format of the buffer? Is all full or half empty? All values are have the same size? **What have you tryied**?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster- Bad Comment man. Doesn't makes sense to me. The question is simple and self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the exact syntax but, if possible, you should use:

```
reinterpret_cast<char *>(buffer[i]);
```

Also see:

[Is there a good way to convert from unsigned char* to char*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708444/is-there-a-good-way-to-convert-from-unsigned-char-to-char)

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` and `memcmp` compare data, they don't copy it...

Anyway, just cast to `char *` and use whatever stdlib function makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If by string you mean a char array, the simplest way in c++ is just to use std::copy, no need to cast anything:

```
unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
char dest[BUFFER_SIZE]

std::copy( buffer, buffer + N, dest );
```

If you mean a std::string, just use the iterator style constructor:

```
std::string dest( buffer, buffer + N );
```